# My apache rewrite only works for the first folder level

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

We have a website where we show clients creative work we have produced for them. We upload raw assets to a path like this:

`x.com/clients/clientName/campaignName/size/`

I have a PHP script which adds our branding, contact information and other information and pulls in the raw creative (usually a swf object). It is in this directory `x.com/clients/index.php` and it accepts a query string parameter `?path` so it knows where to look for the creative.

I am trying to do an apache rewrite in .htaccess so that our designers can upload directly to the known folder structure but so that when you go to `x.com/clients/clientName/campaignName/size/` it should rewrite to `x.com/clients/index.php?path=clientName/campaignName/size/`

I am currently using the following rewrite rule, which works for the first folder level e.g. `x.com/clients/clientName/` does successfully rewrite, but any subsequent folders do not.

`RewriteRule ^clients/([^/\.]+)/?$ /clients/index.php?path=$1 [L]`

My RegEx's are terrible, so I'm stuck on what to do. Any help appreciated, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is only matching urls like `clients/xxxxxx/` because your pattern `[^/\.]+` means `one or many characters except "/" or "."`

With your rule, it can't work for other subdirectories.

You can change your rule by this one

```
RewriteRule ^clients/(.+)$ /clients/index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

To avoid internal server error (code 500 which means an infinite loop in this case), you can do it this way

```
RewriteRule ^clients/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^clients/(.+)$ /clients/index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I get an internal server error when I try using this rewrite rule. Even with no other rewrites in place

Comment: Probably you get the server error, because the RewriteRule matches itself after the redirect - RewriteCond should be added. Check out my answer.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that, sorry. I edited my answer to avoid internal error

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. This worked for me in the end

Answer (score 1):

Is there a special reason you want to use regex? In my opinion you can just catch everything coming after /clients:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)?index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^clients/(.*)$ /clients/index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

The second line is to prevents redirect loops, because the index.php is also in the folder /clients and this would cause never ending redirects.